# What is the purpose of a do-while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I know what do does, and how it cooperates with the while loop, but won't a while loop code be the same, whether or not the do is there?

Comment: A do-while loop will run at least once.

Comment: do while loop does at least one iteration

Comment: it belongs to the check of the while loop. The while loop checks before running and the do while first does something and then check. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) is the in the explain in the oracle docs (bottem sentence)

Comment: [What is a good reason to use a do/while loop?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-good-reason-to-use-a-do-while-loop)

Comment: Step 1: you do google. Step 2: you ask here. No other way around... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there ever a need for a "do {...} while ( )" loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994905/is-there-ever-a-need-for-a-do-while-loop) and [Why use a “do while” loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003456/why-use-a-do-while-loop)

Comment: Well, there is an obvious difference: in do/while, the condition for continuation is evaluated _after_ each loop, not before... And this can have its uses as well. So, what is your real question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
while(condition){
   myFunction();
}
```

and

```
do{
   myFunction();
}while(condition);
```

The second form executes `myFunction()` at least once then checks the `condition`! To do so with a `while` loop you've to write:

```
myFunction();

while(condition){
   myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The biggest difference between while and do-while statement is, whether it is executed at least one time or not.

```
while(false)
 printf("print!");
```

with this statement, the program will never print the string. However,

```
do{
    printf("print!");
}while(false);
```

with this statement, the program will print the string once.

But many people don't recommend to use do-while statement--because it can be substituted with while statement. It doesn't mean that do-while statement is critically harmful, but it is rarely used.

In fact, for loop is the most safe and recommended way because the programmer can handle the iteration number, loop conditions, and increasing variables easily. So if you don't have any specific reason that you have to use while loop, just use for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use do-while() construct when you have to get your task executed at least once even if condition fails. 
Use while() when you your task to be executed only on certain condition success.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is with "do-while" loop will be executed at least one time. With "while" loop with false condition the loop body will not be executed.

Answer (score -1):

if you write the "loop" like so (without the `do` as in your question):

```
int i=0;
{
    System.out.println(i++);
}while(i<10);
```

it will just print out `0` (nothing more), and **not** loop 10 times.. so no, the loop won't be the same if the do isnt there.