# For Loop vs. Do…While

Tags: javascript, loops

### Background

I'm just learning JavaScript and I thought that a good way to start was to code [my own dice roller for an RPG I play](https://misc.excess-advantage.com/wrathglory/dice). For this game you roll a handful of six-sided dice where each 4 or 5 is worth one success and each 6 is worth 2 successes.

I have a function that rolls the dice and passes the rolls, via an array, to another function that HTML-ifies it for display on the webpage.

### The Code

In order to roll the dice, I have what I think is the standard dice roller function (the `sides` variable is because sometimes you can roll dice that have sides other than 6, so I made the function usable for all dice rolls):

```
function rollDice(sides) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*sides) + 1;
}
```

Because the number of dice you roll varies, my main function calls this `rollDice()` function a number of times and puts each result in an array.

This is the main function, where `number` is the number of dice to roll:

```
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  for (i=0; i<number; i++){
    results.push(rollDice(6));
  }
  return results;
}
```

However, I have since learned of the `do…while` loop, and have managed to refactor it thusly:

```
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  do {
    results.push(rollDice(6));
  } while (results.length < number)
  return results;
}
```

### The Actual Question

Which loop is more 'correct' or best practice to use? `for` or `do…while`?

Comment: `for` loops are definitely more common, and I wouldn't look twice at the first example. But as you've discovered, `do...while` loops can in some situations provide a very pleasing solution! I wouldn't say either of these is strictly more correct than the other

Comment: Consider, however, what you want to happen when `number` is less than one.

Comment: Depends on your requirements.  Do... While loop run at least one time if condition not match when for loop runs only if condition match

Comment: if `number` never touches 0 or below, I think the `do... while` will do. but I really rarely see `do... while` in my own experience.

Comment: I agree with everyone who says thy rarely see do...while in the wild although there's nothing necessarily WRONG with using it in the right situation. I will add, though, that in school I was discouraged from using it for reasons similar to what was outlined in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994905/is-there-ever-a-need-for-a-do-while-loop . That's a bit subjective, however :)

Comment: If you haven't researched it yet you may also be interested in `forEach` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Since you’re always rolling at least one die, `number` will never be less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple `while` loop which is equivalent to your `for` loop example.

```
function dice(number) {
  let results = [];
  while (results.length < number) {
    results.push(rollDice(6));
  }
  return results;
}
```

I like the readability of this the best (partly because it doesn't create an extra iterator variable), but the `for` loop is fine too. The `do...while` loop works but the extra syntax is unnecessary.

Comment: Huh, i didn’t even think of a plain `while` loop. Thanks!